# Asp .net identity multiple logins with different emails

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity-2

I am having some trouble using the .net identity, because I would like to link multiple social accounts even if they don't have the same email.
My ideal workflow would be. I log in with one of the external providers and after that, on my profile page I would link my other social accounts.
The problem is that the user identity class is fixed with one email and I can't override the user login class to add an email too.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default allot of Identity Providerds via OAuth/OpenId will not send back the users email address. Therefore you have to either add to your Oauth/OpenId claims request one for email OR prompt the user to enter their email address for that provider. That being said, you shouldn't need the Email from individual providers as the way you identify a user via OAuth/OpenId provider is through their Provider Key which is stored inside of the AspNetUserLogins table.

The patern for asp identity is you have a user object which optionally has an email address, then you add login providers as such as facebook/gmail/etc by storing the unique user ID from that provider inside of the AspNetUserLogins table which relate back to the user. So by default your not supposed to have emails for facebook/gmail/etc.

Personally I havn't used the following [ASP.NET Identity Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) but from a quick glance it looks like it could help you with understanding how to use Identity Providers.

Answer (score 0):

I extended the Identity base classes to include an Email property on the Login table, and then improved the Claims asks to OAuth providers to ask for Email.

Each new social login I record the Email used, which allows us to, among other things, automatically merge accounts for the same email. For example, registering with Google then forgetting and registering with Facebook, we save you time and just add the FB Login to your existing account and off you go, no nightmares where you have a blank account suddenly.

What we haven't sorted is the other half of your question, with multiple Email and Pass. I guess the laziest way would be to extend Visitor/AspNetUser to a Parent Visitor. Then when a user registers a second email/pass they'd be able to access their one merged account. But the use case for that is very limited; I think it's better to limit users to one email/pass, infinite socials, and if they Merge accounts, have them pick which email they want the final account to use.